# What kind of sorcery is this? CSS? Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I was inspecting this Microsoft's site: https://www.windowsazure.com

Using chrome's developer tools I started moving things around (basically css stuff). Then I notice some cool features, if you modify css properties, the site will show a transition from the previous state to the new one, this will happen with color properties, but it works on paddings and images too. This is great because they don't have to care about every single new animation it will just happen when css changes!

So my question is, what technology is this? CSS3? Javascript? do you know any documentation where it explains how to accomplish this?

Comment: Check out http://daneden.me/animate/ for a bunch of examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing the [CSS3 `transition` property](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understanding-css3-transitions/).

Comment: I haven't taken a look at CSS3 new features, I guess I must!