# Why would they place the whole web site in a form element?

Tags: html, css, forms

Taken from this question,

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978199/what-kind-of-sorcery-is-this-css-javascript)

And this site,

[web site](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/)

Why would they place the web site within a `form` element.

```
<form id="RunwayMasterForm" action="/en-us/" method="post">
```

Looking at the markup structure, the `form` element is a direct child of the `body` and all other elements are contained within the `form` element.

Why would they do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the original form of Microsoft's [ASP.Net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) (Web Forms), all pages generated markup that included a single form tag wrapping everything.

My guess is that either the developer originally created the page as part of an ASP.Net WebForms "solution", and since migrated away from that framework without removing the form tag, or just developed a mis-understanding of this as being a kind of standard, though  working with such solutions over a period of time.

**udpate** looking at the link ([Windows Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/)) in the SO question you referenced, this is a current MS page -- yes, indeed, this is WebForms in action.

Answer (score 1):

Many server side languages, (particularly those with a high level of abstraction, like ASP.net) deal with user interaction through standard form input.

Answer (score 1):

These pages are probably coming from a ASP.NET web application.

In ASP.NET all server controls must appear within a form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because they are using ASP.NET WebForms, which attempt to abstract away as much of web development as possible and make it look like desktop application development — an approach which results in lots of compromises and code that doesn't meet best practises.